# Why does my .desktop-file in home/USER/.local/share/applications needs to be owned by root?

Tags: .desktop, chown

I [downloaded](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux) IDEA IntelliJ Community Edition, extraced it, copied the extracted files to `/opt/i` and run `sudo ./idea.sh` for installation. It created a launcher calld `jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop`in `/home/USER/.local/share/applications` which is owned by `root`. I think this is wrong, because my other files there are owned by me (USER).

So I changed ownership to USER. Now the program wont startup.

Can someone please explain why I have to start the `.desktop`-file in my local folder being owned as `root`?

The command it executes is `"/opt/i/bin/idea.sh" %f`

Comment: There would have been no reason to run `./idea.sh` as root.  Maybe try again. (delete the .desktop & ~/.IntelliJIdea2018.1

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I re-installed accordingly. However, I would still be interested in an answer to why a desktop file run as `root` will open up the program, and without it will not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the launch icon is owned by your current USER but the installation folder is owned by root. Have you check the permission on /opt/i?